# mySQL Group By Max query not yielding correct result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

In mySQL I have a view called riskscores:

```
SELECT * FROM Psag.riskscores WHERE AdmissionID = 52;
```

that gives:

```
AdmissionID RiskDate      RiskID RiskScore
'52',       '2020-04-22', '83',  '16'
'52',       '2020-04-15', '84',  '40'
'52',       '2020-04-08', '82',  '51'
'52',       '2020-04-01', '81',  '106'
'52',       '2020-03-25', '18',  '133'
'52',       '2020-03-18', '17',  '133'
```

I've added the WHERE clause to keep the data brief.

Then I query this view with:

```
SELECT max(RiskDate) AS LatestDate, AdmissionID, RiskScore FROM riskscores
WHERE AdmissionID=52
GROUP BY AdmissionID;
```

I get:

```
LatestDate    AdmissionID RiskScore
'2020-04-22', '52',       '133'
```

I'm expecting the RiskScore to be 16 not 133 given that the row of the LatestDate value '2020-04-22' has that score.

I have already set

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

Any help gratefully received

Comment: the non aggregated columns are indeterminate , I get a different outcome to you and you logic is flawed you should be picking the row WHERE the max riskdate is present.

Comment: If I group by LatestDate I get an error code 1056 Can't group on 'LatestDate'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the may riskdate and then join it with the table, if there mare more than one dates linking you must select a score in my case the max
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE riskscores (
  `AdmissionID` INTEGER,
  `RiskDate` date,
  `RiskID` INTEGER,
  `RiskScore`INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO riskscores
  (`AdmissionID`, `RiskDate`, `RiskID`, `RiskScore`)
VALUES
  ('52', '2020-04-22', '83', '16'),
  ('52', '2020-04-15', '84', '40'),
  ('52', '2020-04-08', '82', '51'),
  ('52', '2020-04-01', '81', '106'),
  ('52', '2020-03-25', '18', '133'),
  ('52', '2020-03-18', '17', '133');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
MIN(LatestDate)
, r.AdmissionID
, MAX(RiskScore )
FROM riskscores r
INNER JOIN
(SELECT max(RiskDate) AS LatestDate
, AdmissionID
FROM riskscores
GROUP BY AdmissionID) rm
ON r.AdmissionID = rm.AdmissionID AND r.RiskDate = rm.LatestDate
WHERE r.AdmissionID=52
GROUP BY r. AdmissionID;

| MIN(LatestDate) | MAX(RiskScore ) | AdmissionID |
| --------------- | --------------- | ----------- |
| 2020-04-22      | 16              | 52          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Thanks. That absolutely works. Now I'm going to figure out exactly how! Not sure exactly why you used Min(LatestDate) when it felt like I needed the opposite, but fair play to you, you're spot on! Thanks :-)

Comment: Only_Full_Group Allows in tghe Select only rows **without** any aggregation functions that are in the GROUP BY as here there is only AdmissionID inn the GROUP By you have to tell MYSQL what to to with the others, I also could have put the riskdate in the Group by as we only have one date . Try it

Answer (score 0):

the non aggregated columns are indeterminate , I get a different outcome to you and your logic is flawed you should be picking the row WHERE the max riskdate is present

```
select admissionid,riskdate,riskid,riskscore
from t
where admissionid = 52 and
        riskdate = (select max(riskdate) from t t1 where t1.admissionid = t.admissionid )
```